# Extract All Zipped Files to Same Directory Using Python

Tags: python, zip

I have a large amount of zipped files in a single directory that I would like to decompress and save them to the same directory and with the same name as the zipped file.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the `zipfile` module? If so, which specific problems have you found?

Comment: No, I haven't taken a look at the zipfile module.  I'll take a look and get back to you if I can't solve the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with something like:

```
import glob
import os
import zipfile

zip_files = glob.glob('*.zip')

for zip_filename in zip_files:
    dir_name = os.path.splitext(zip_filename)[0]
    os.mkdir(dir_name)
    zip_handler = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, "r")
    zip_handler.extractall(dir_name)
```

Sorry, I don't have time to test this code; any bug is left as an exercise for you.

[Updated with eumiro's suggestion]

Comment: Once you `import os`, you can use it to manipulate filenames too. `dir_name = os.path.splitext(zip_filename)[0]` may be more readable.